# why autoplay not working on page refresh using html5 audio?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I have html5 audio like this in my page

```
 <audio id="audioplayer" playsinline controls muted loop autoplay hidden>
            <source src="audio/muzyka_meed_loop.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
  </audio>
```

Here I am adding a random number to audio src to prevent cache

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        document.querySelector('#audioplayer source').setAttribute('src', 'audio/muzyka_meed_loop.mp3?rand=' + Math.random());

    })
</script>
```

But now when I refresh the page the audio is not playing while there is autoplay on audio tag

Here is live page : [live demo](https://meed.audiencevideo.com/)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the autoplay attribute:

```
 <audio id="audioplayer" src="audio/muzyka_meed_loop.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" loop="loop"> </audio>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("audioplayer").play();
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#audioplayer").get(0).play();
});
```

Comment: I am checking I will let you know

Comment: Hii Vikas I tried your solution here is live demo https://meed.audiencevideo.com/ , still facing the problem when I test on different computers ,I have added the window.onload at the head tag check out .

Comment: @user9964622 different computers means? it's working on some computer and not others?

Comment: Yes, try it in different browser eg opera or firefox

Answer (score 0):

I found solution recently. You need to call videoplayer.play() method in onLoadedData event on HTML video element. This is example in React:

```
<video src={videoSource} ref={videoPlayer} onLoadedData={() => videoPlayer.current.play()}/>
```

I'm guessing it works with audio as well.